# Snowflake execute a query result

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a stored procedure where output is more than 1 row.  is there way to have the output execute , similar to SQLPRINT

Here is code for stored procedure

```
create or replace procedure DIMENSIONS.DBMETA.GET_TABLES()
    returns TABLE (SQL_SCRIPT VARCHAR)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    AS
    $$
declare res RESULTSET DEFAULT (  SELECT
                            CONCAT('INSERT INTO DIMENSIONS.DBMETA.TABLES(DATABASE_ID, DB_NAME, SCHEMA_ID, DATABASE_TABLE_ID, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_CREATE_DATE, OBJECT_TYPE, CREATE_BY_USER_ID) ','SELECT DB.DATABASE_ID,DB.SERVER_ID,DB.DATABASE_NAME,SCH.SCHEMA_ID,ISC.TABLE_NAME,ISC.CREATED,ISC.TABLE_TYPE,999 AS CREATE_BY_USER_ID FROM ',DB.DATABASE_NAME,'.','INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ISC ' ,
                            ' JOIN DIMENSIONS.DBMETA.DATABASES DB ON ISC.TABLE_CATALOG = DB.DATABASE_NAME AND DB.SERVER_ID = 320'
                                ,'JOIN DIMENSIONS.DBMETA.SCHEMAS SCH ON ISC.TABLE_SCHEMA = SCH.SCHEMA_NAME AND DB.DATABASE_ID = SCH.DATABASE_ID'
                            , ' LEFT JOIN DIMENSIONS.DBMETA.VW_TABLES SC '
                            ,'ON ISC.TABLE_CATALOG = SC.DATABASE_NAME AND ISC.TABLE_SCHEMA = SC.SCHEMA_NAME AND SC.SERVER_ID = DB.SERVER_ID  AND SC.TABLE_NAME = ISC.TABLE_NAME'
                            ,' WHERE SC.TABLE_NAME IS NULL') AS SQL_SCRIPT
  FROM DIMENSIONS.DBMETA.DATABASES DB
  WHERE DB.SERVER_ID = 320);
BEGIN
    RETURN TABLE (res);
END;
$$
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Pls run `select * from table(DIMENSIONS.DBMETA.GET_TABLES())`

Comment: If you want the results to execute then why not do this within the SP? Just loop through the resultset executing each row

Comment: how would i do that?  the rowcount can vary with each run

Comment: Code that loops through a resultset wouldn’t care how many records there were - so I’m not sure why you are concerned about the rowcount? There are examples of this type of code here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/resultsets#label-snowscript-resultsets-example-resultset-cursor

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to executes a string that contains a SQL statement.

For example, try something like `execute immediate ('select current_timestamp;');`

See https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate.